# Can not convert attribut "type" in xml string to json string by Restlet StringRepresentation class

Tags: java, xml, json, restlet

I used StringRepresentation java class in Restlet to convert a xml string to json string. There's a "type" attribute in my xml string, for example:

```
<contacts>
   <contact index="0" type="type1" name="contact1">
   <contact index="1" type="type2" name="contact2"> 
</contacts>
```

After converting, I found everything is ok except attribute "type" which is not in the json string result.

I know "type" is a special name in many cases. Is there any config in Restlet that i can set to let StringRepresentation class treat "type" as a common attribute name?

Comment: have you tried serializing to a different fieldname using @JsonProperty("otherfieldname") (jackson annotation)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by myself. the answer is setTypeHintsEnabled(false) in XMLSerializer. XMLSerializer filtered out the attribute "type", not StringPresentation. Here is the code:

```
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
serializer.setTypeHintsEnabled(false);
result = new StringRepresentation(serializer.read(xml).toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, Language.ALL, CharacterSet.UTF_8);
```